# Why 'beforepaste' event is not fired in webkit?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, dom-events

`beforecopy` event is fired, but `beforepaste` event isn't fired. Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">#editor{width:300px; height:300px; border: 1px solid black;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="editor" contentEditable="true">editor</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var elEditor = document.getElementById("editor");

elEditor.addEventListener('beforecopy', function(e){
    console.log('beforecopy');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}); 

elEditor.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
    console.log('copy');
}); 

elEditor.addEventListener('beforepaste', function(e){
    console.log('beforepaste');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}); 

elEditor.addEventListener('paste', function(e){
    console.log('paste')
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- [Using the Pasteboard From JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/CopyAndPaste.html)
- fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/BjR9q/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Chrome 23.0.1271.95 on OS X 10.8.2, `onbeforepaste` only triggers when the user causes a context menu to pop up.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljxqbxkf.php:

> Occurs before the contents of the clipboard are pasted into the document and provides a possibility to enable the **Paste menu item**.

Right-clicking the text-box causes the `onbeforepaste` event to fire, but not pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>v</kbd>.

If it's any consolation, the `onpaste` event fires before the text is actually pasted, in my tests, so I would just use the `onpaste` event instead.

Comment: Unless, of course, you want to know what the text that is being pasted is (perhaps to perform some pre-processing before pasting)

Comment: As far as I know, onbeforepaste becomes more useful with pasting in safari, since safari will prevent paste from happening unless it's a contentEditable.